# How homological data change upon quotienting out a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm interested in the following question. Consider a chain complex of the form
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
where A and B and C consist of free R-modules. The unlabeled maps can be considered as zero maps.

(Additional assumptions that may or may not be useful: More concretely I would like these modules to be free modules of a (Laurent) polynomial ring with rank n, q, m respectively. )

We can then look at the homological data of this chain complex and define $H_0 = C/\mathrm{im}(g)$, $H_1 = \mathrm{ker}(g)/\mathrm{im}(f)$, $H_2 = \mathrm{ker}(f)$. Suppose further that
\begin{equation}
H_1 = 0
\end{equation} at this stage. I am wondering if we can say anything at all about the homological data of the following chain complex:

$I$ is an ideal that is also finitely generated (more concretely they can just be a finite collection of polynomials). We have then an induced chain complex
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow A/I \xrightarrow{f} B/I \xrightarrow{g} C/I \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}

More specifically, suppose for some $I$ $H_1$ now becomes non-trivial. Can we deduce anything about how $H_0$ and $H_2$ changes?

Comment: what is your question?. Also $I$ is a submodule of which module?

Comment: Maybe you meant ideal?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace  My question is, knowing that $H_1=0$ before the quotient, can one relate $H_0(A/I)$ to $H_1(A/I)$ after the quotient? Can one say something like 'if $H_0(A/I)$ is the same as before, then $H_1(A/I)$ is still zero' or 'if $H_1(A/I)$ is non-zero then $H_0(A/I)$ should be different'.

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t being clear. Let’s assume I is an ideal. I just vaguely have in mind that I is a module generated by a finite number of polynomials. Is that the same as an ideal?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I’m trying to understand your first comment. So we are trying to extract homological information of F(A)->F(B)->F(C), F being a tensor product functor. I’m still new to spectral sequences so am curious where to go from here. So I know Tor functor is a derived functor from tensor product functor, but here F might not be left or right exact. Is that why we need the further machinery of spectral sequence? Can you be a bit specific about the mathematical structure I should look for here?